# How to get an element with condition of its child element

Tags: python, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am doing on a crawling project using Python and Selenium. I am confusing about how to get an element with the condition of its child element from XML. For example, we have an XML like below:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href='http://foo.com'>
            <span>foo</span>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to get `a` tag with the condition of `span` tag which contains 'foo'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `XPath` for this:

```
//a[span[.="foo"]]
```

This means `<a>` tag which has a direct child with the text `"foo"`.

If the span is a decedent you can add `//` to the `span` in the `XPath`:

```
//a[//span[.="foo"]]
```

Answer (score -1):

beautifulSoup should get you the content you want

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("span"))
```

there are many more functions. You can read more [here](http://zetcode.com/python/beautifulsoup/)

Comment: This isn't what OP wants. He asks for `a` elements that contain a `span` with text `foo`